# Create a URL on a sharepoint site which links a page that links to another page

Tags: url, sharepoint

I have a problem with a sharepoint website that I'm working on. It's a calendar site with a signup form. The signup form is on a different page. The problem occurs when I try to link directly to the signup form and not the calender activity page.

Basically, the signup form does not understand which calendar activity you want to sign up on, unless your previous page was that specific activity page. It seems like there's some sort of meta data that doesn't get registered if link directly to the sign up form.

So I need to create a URL that links to the signup form, as if I was standing on its calendar activity page.

Is this even possible?

Comment: how about sending a user to the calender page like `calender.php?f=forward` and then gets forwarded to the signup page when calender.php receives the `f` variable and prints out `window.location.href`

Comment: HM, I dont understand. It's a sharepoint site. IF that helps. x)

Comment: that's why you have to explain more in your description and choose your tags well. i'm sorry i don't know that site and can't help you :( how about fixing your question and write down everything you know and someone might help you answer :) cheers

Comment: Sorry about that. Wasted your time. I've updated the question. Thanks!